# Why does Collections.ncopies return a mutable collection?

Tags: java, collections

Class `java.util.Collections` has method `nCopies()`.
The documentation for this method says that it returns an immutable copy of collection containing *n* copies of same element.

However in the below code I am able to modify the list and add a new element to the collection. How is this possible in an immutable collection?
(See line number 3, below.)

```
1) List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(5, "Some string"));

2) System.out.println(list);

3) list.add("Some other string");

4) System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(5, "Chinese Virus")) -- creates a new list, and you are adding to that new list, that is not immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you create a new modifiable `ArrayList` out of the returned list?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(5, "Some string"));
```

this is essentially the same as

```
List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.nCopies(5, "Some string");
List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<>(unmodifiableList);

unmodifiableList.remove(0); // will throw UnsupportedOperationException
modifiableList.remove(0); // will work without issues
```

In the above example `modifiableList` is a List containing the same elements as `unmodifiableList` but otherwise it's just an ordinary `ArrayList` that allows adding and removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't modifying the collection returned from `nCopies` - you've created a new `ArrayList` and copied the contents into it. Once the copying is done, it's just a normal `ArrayList`, and there's no reason you won't be able to add to it.